# How to build a gem from rails source code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to make a gem from rails source code and install the gem.

After clone the master repository of rails, I tried as follow.

```
$>gem build rails.gemspec 
$>gem install rails-4.2.0.alpha.gem
```

It did not work. I also tried `$>rake install` which did not work either.

Looking forward your help!

Comment: Given what you wrote I would reconsider "building" rails from source and changing it's code by yourself.

Comment: Rails *is* source code... not sure what you're trying to achieve but if you follow a standard installation you will end up with all the rails source and gem sources and a working app.

Comment: I wanted to get the latest rails source code. If I set the version of rails as 4.2.0.alpha, is the source code same as the code in master git repository of rails? Also where can I find the source code once I installed a gem?

Comment: I think I need to change my question as "How to make a rails gem from rails source code?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a script in the root directory which builds from source and installs the gems. It's called install.rb. You can use it by running the following:

```
ruby install.rb 4.2.0.alpha
```

Note: At the time of writing this the arel gem needs to be built from source and installed separately before running the install script above. This is because the version constraints in rails are requiring a version of arel which has not yet been released onto rubygems.org.

Comment: Thanks! _arel_ gem was the problem when I tried to run `rake install` or `rake build`. I should have installed _arel_ gem separately. Thanks again!